# How can I hide the X-Axis in D3 (DynamicDataDisplay) Plotter?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I would like to be able to hide the X-Axis (Labels, Ticks, etc) in the ChartPlotter of D3 (DynamicDataDisplay). The amount of documentation available for D3 is basically non-existent.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see [in the sources](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/31108#1509251) the AxisBase is a ContentControl so you should be able to make it invisible.

That might be too crude so you could also take a look at [the default style/template](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/31108#1509253), copy it and change it to hide/remove those part that you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
plotter.HorizontalAxis.Remove();
```

in code-behind. Just done it in my WPF app.

Answer (score -1):

`MainVerticalAxisVisibility="Collapsed"` works